# Has anyone ever played SMB3 level 1-2 and skipped straight to level 6 (the ice level)?

Tags: super-mario-bros-3

I very vaguely remember in level 1-2 there was a pipe I went though that took me straight to level 6 (the ice level). But I’ve tried everything. I do think you had the star power up and only a few seconds to get to the correct pipe. As soon as you went though it transported you straight to the ice level.

It was NOT A whistle. I repeat it was NOT a whistle.

I’ve been playing on my Switch since it’s portable but haven’t been able to figure it  back out. Not sure if it was a programming glitch since I first found it on my NES clsssic.  I may need to break it out again since that’s where I did it.

But anyone ever figured it out? I do remember figuring it out on accident though.

Comment: There's certainly not meant to be any kind of warp from 1-2. I'd be really interested if you could get it to work on the NES Classic - I know that the regular Wrong Warp setup for SMB3 doesn't work on the NES Classic, as the emulator used isn't perfectly accurate.

Comment: Ok I sort of have it figured out I think… although I’m not fast enough. If you have an NES classic try this. Go though level 1-2. Hit the block that has the P but don’t use it yet. Kill all goombas. Go through to where the star power is. Hit it just to the right so the star moves left. Chase it but don’t grab it until it reaches the two bouncy blocks. Grab it quickly run left to the P and jump on it. Then make your way up to the pipe at the top and go down before the star power ends. Idk if this is right but if you can try it let me know

Comment: Okay, I asked the world record holder for Super Mario Bros 3 speedruns (mitchflowerpower), and he said he's never heard of any way to warp from 1-2; though he isn't familiar with the NES classic version. If you could get video evidence of it, it could certainly shake up the speedrun scene.

Comment: Upon further review of playing all the levels in world one it was definitely 1-2. Now someone who’s super fast and can reply the level over and over can maybe test it out. Test every single pipe when you have the star power (also test with Luigi in case the glitch was him). 

I know for sure I did it a few times because I had a friend over and we were trying to beat the game. And the fact I had NEVER played the ice world prior to this “glitch”. 
I only came on here because I knew someone with quick fingers can figure it out if I can’t.

Answer (score 1):

Seems as though you did a glitch. If you are unable to replicate it, even after multiple tries, then yeah- glitch. I don't know much about SMB3, but I've seen a few things that would make me think so, such as for each level there is a certain amount of frames you can finish it in. Also, the different platform may be what's causing that- It may have gotten patched.

Comment: I did it a few times but I wish I would of wrote down exactly what I did. If nobody else has done it I’m going to assume it’s just on the nes classic. (Not the original system. It was the one that came out in 2017)

Comment: Ah, alright.  I thought maybe it'd be the original system.